# How to write function of Fortran f90 in a separate file?

Tags: function, fortran

I want to write function in a separate file myfunction.f90 and how to modify test.f90 to call it

```
program test
    implicit none
    external myfunc
    real :: x,myfunc
    x = 5
    write(*,*) myfunc(x)
end program test


function myfunc(x)
    implicit none
    real :: myfunc,x
    myfunc = x**2
end function myfunc
```

I separate into 2 files test.f90

```
program test
    implicit none
    external myfunc
    real :: x,myfunc
    x = 5
    write(*,*) myfunc(x)
end program test
```

and myfunc.f90

```
function myfunc(x)
    implicit none
    real :: myfunc,x
    myfunc = x**2
end function myfunc
```

But it does not work

Comment: How are you compiling these, and in what way does this 'not work'?

Comment: Please show the exact copy of your compilation command and of the complete error output. See [ask].

Comment: While it is possible to achieve your aim, with suitable compilation statement(s), it's not a very good idea.  Much better would be to wrap `myfunc` into a `module` for separate compilation, and to drop the use of `external` routines. Lots of Qs and As about that on this site.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code, and wrap the function into module mymod, and add use mymod in the program test. But VSC throwed error

Comment: *I use Visual Studio Code, and wrap the function into module mymod* that's not what your code shows. Don't waste our time showing us the wrong code.

Comment: You really have to show the actual latest code you are compiling, the command you are executing and the complete error output.

Comment: You always have the option to add the function after a `contains` statement inside the `program` code block (for one file solution).  Otherwise, create a separate module file and add the function after its `contains` statement and include the module file in the compilation command.

Comment: If you wrap the function with module mymod ......   end module then VSC throws error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the new complete code and the **complete** error output. Even the code that you are currently showing is perfectly legal and must work when correctly compiled and run. External might not be nice and modern, but it is perfectly legal Fortran.

Comment: https://iraspa.org/blog/visual-studio-code-c-cpp-fortran-with-multiple-source-files/

Answer (score -1):

The canonical solution is to create a file with a `module` that includes all your functions after the `contains` keyword.

Then reference the module in your program with `use mymodule` and include both files to the compiler command.